# Cant resolve .onion domains

Tags: debian, tor

After installing tor I can't resolve onion domains, but have no problems with normal domains.

```sh
curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
blabla
```

but:

```sh
curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 https://protonirockerxow.onion/
```

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: protonirockerxow.onion

Answer (score 0):

Use the --socks5-hostname option like this:

```
curl --socks5-hostname  "127.0.0.1:9050" "http://site.onion/"
```

Useful reading: [curl ootw: –socks5](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2020/05/26/curl-ootw-socks5/)